# PHP Memory Limit on creation of CSV from db - How to reduce memory that PHP uses?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, mysqli, download

Am running a db query here, and using mysqli with `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` in order to execute the query faster.  But there is php manipulation of data needed here, so it's not as simple as just writing to a CSV file on each row returned.  I know that the database query is finishing (even though it is taking a long time), but the db query does finish, so the problem has to be in the PHP memory side, cause I'm getting a 504 Gateway Timeout Error.  My code for this is as follows:

```
global $wpdb, $root_dir;

if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
    $root_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/';
else
    $root_dir = ABSPATH;

require_once($root_dir . 'wp-config.php');
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals();

$start_date = !empty($_GET['start']) ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['start']) : '';
$end_date = !empty($_GET['end']) ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['end']) : '';

$append = array();

if (!empty($start_date))
    $append[] = $start_date->format('Y-m-d');

if (!empty($end_date))
    $append[] = $end_date->format('Y-m-d');

$filename = 'user-export' . (!empty($append) ? '_' . implode('_', $append) : '');

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . ".csv\"");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");


ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);

$headers = array('Order Date/Time', 'Name', 'Billing Address', 'Shipping Address', 'Phone', 'Email Address');
$meta_keys = array('_billing_first_name', '_billing_last_name', '_billing_address_1', '_billing_address_2', '_billing_city', '_billing_state', '_billing_postcode', '_billing_email', '_billing_country', '_billing_phone', '_shipping_address_1', '_shipping_address_2', '_shipping_city', '_shipping_state', '_shipping_postcode', '_shipping_country');
$csv_data = $emails = $order_ids_skipped = $meta = array();

// Using an unbuffered query...
$mysqli  = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$uresult = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT p.ID, p.post_date, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key IN ('" . implode("','", $meta_keys) . "'))
    WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' AND p.post_status IN ('wc-sent-delivery', 'wc-awaiting-delivery', 'wc-completed')" . (!empty($start_date) && !empty($end_date) ? " AND (p.post_date >= '" . $start_date->format('Y-m-d') . " 00:00:00' AND p.post_date <= '" . $end_date->format('Y-m-d') . " 23:59:59')" : "") . "
    ORDER BY p.post_date DESC", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

if ($uresult) 
{
    while ($order_query = $uresult->fetch_assoc())
    {
        // If the email already exists, continue...
        if ($order_query['meta_key'] == '_billing_email' && !empty($emails) && in_array($order_query['meta_value'], $emails))
        {
            if (isset($csv_data[$order_query['ID']]))
                unset($csv_data[$order_query['ID']]);

            if (isset($meta[$order_query['ID']]))
                unset($meta[$order_query['ID']]);

            $order_ids_skipped[] = $order_query['ID'];

            continue;
        }

        if (in_array($order_query['ID'], $order_ids_skipped)) continue;

        if (!isset($csv_data[$order_query['ID']]))
            $csv_data[$order_query['ID']] = array(
                'order_date' => $order_query['post_date']
            );

        $meta[$order_query['ID']][$order_query['meta_key']] = $order_query['meta_value'];

        if ($order_query['meta_key'] == '_billing_email')
            $emails[] = $order_query['meta_value'];
    }
}
$uresult->close();

if (!empty($meta))
{
    foreach($meta as $order_id => $meta_data)
    {
        $billing = array(
            'addr1' => !empty($meta_data['_billing_address_1']) ? $meta_data['_billing_address_1'] : '',
            'addr2' => !empty($meta_data['_billing_address_2']) ? $meta_data['_billing_address_2'] : '',
            'city' => !empty($meta_data['_billing_city']) ? $meta_data['_billing_city'] : '',
            'state' => !empty($meta_data['_billing_state']) ? $meta_data['_billing_state'] : '',
            'zip' => !empty($meta_data['_billing_postcode']) ? $meta_data['_billing_postcode'] : '',
            'country' => !empty($meta_data['_billing_country']) ? $meta_data['_billing_country'] : ''
        );
        $shipping = array(
            'addr1' => !empty($meta_data['_shipping_address_1']) ? $meta_data['_shipping_address_1'] : '',
            'addr2' => !empty($meta_data['_shipping_address_2']) ? $meta_data['_shipping_address_2'] : '',
            'city' => !empty($meta_data['_shipping_city']) ? $meta_data['_shipping_city'] : '',
            'state' => !empty($meta_data['_shipping_state']) ? $meta_data['_shipping_state'] : '',
            'zip' => !empty($meta_data['_shipping_postcode']) ? $meta_data['_shipping_postcode'] : '',
            'country' => !empty($meta_data['_shipping_country']) ? $meta_data['_shipping_country'] : ''
        );

        $csv_data[$order_id]['name'] = !empty($meta_data['_billing_last_name']) ? trim($meta_data['_billing_first_name']) . ' ' . trim($meta_data['_billing_last_name']) : trim($meta_data['_billing_first_name']);
        $csv_data[$order_id]['billing'] = implode(', ', array_filter($billing));
        $csv_data[$order_id]['shipping'] = implode(', ', array_filter($shipping));
        $csv_data[$order_id]['phone'] = !empty($meta_data['_billing_phone']) ? $meta_data['_billing_phone'] : '';
        $csv_data[$order_id]['email'] = !empty($meta_data['_billing_email']) ? $meta_data['_billing_email'] : '';
    }


    if (!empty($csv_data))
        build_csv_file($csv_data, $headers);
}

// No need to continue here.
exit;

function str_putcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"')
{
    // $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+b');
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'r+b');
    fputcsv($fp, $input, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    rewind($fp);
    rtrim(stream_get_contents($fp), "\n");
    fclose($fp);
    // return $data;
}

function build_csv_file($data, $headers)
{
    global $root_dir;

    $output = '';

    if (empty($data))
        return array();

    if (!empty($headers))
        str_putcsv($headers, ',', '"') . PHP_EOL;

    foreach($data as $part)
        str_putcsv($part, ',', '"') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Saving this file as testing.php and executing the following url like so from the root of wordpress:

https://example.com/testing.php?start=2010-03-05&end=2018-03-05

Just returns a 504 gateway error.  This is definitely a PHP Memory Limit problem, however, I thought that a CSV file can be streamed and even using `php://output` here.  Not sure how to better handle this in order to reduce PHP Memory being used, or if there is even a way to do this properly while still maintaining the data correctly.

Can anyone help me please?  Very much appreciated.  I am using PHP version 7.2 I believe.  You'd think that php would be able to handle memory better these days.  I believe my PHP Memory is maxed out at 1024MB.  I seem to be exceeding the PHP Memory limit all of the time anymore.  Is becoming a real nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

where you're declaring variable $meta

```
if (isset($meta[$order_query['ID']]))
```

also, it would be wise to do a debug by putting exit on each block of statements to know which block of codes consumes that much memory and you can optimize that part only

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are saying here.  The check for `isset($meta[$order_query['ID']]))` unsets the `$meta[$order_query['ID']]` array key, so unsetting should free up memory afaik.  But if I exit during the loop here, it will not finish the loop ever and how does that help me to know which block is consuming memory?  Can you give me an example perhaps?

Comment: I could not see a variable declaration code for $meta like `$meta = []` also you could use wp built in query functions instead of the raw query approach.

Comment: wp built-in function like `$wpdb->get_results` are using stored queries, and this causes use problem that it never finishes it's query.

Comment: I must've overlooked the declaration of `$meta` variable, will add it now.  Not sure if it will help any though.

Comment: Defining the `$meta` variable did not make any difference.  Thanks for trying here.  If you have any further advice, would love to hear it.

Comment: `$wpdb` queries add much overhead to such a simple query.  This overhead slows down the processing of queries, especially huge data sets.

Comment: it won't help to decrease the execution time though.I think the execution time maxes at the csv build function so it would be wise to `die(print_r($csv_data))` to check the final result and I recommend to use Woocommerce's wc_get_orders function to fetch the orders (I believe your using woocommerce) and you may not need to remove the duplications manually (current duplication removal doesn't make much sense to me) just get the orders and send to the csv with pre-formatting if needed

Comment: `wc_get_order` function is even slower than accessing the database directly.  I have tried the die() after echoing the dump of `$csv_data`, the dump of `$csv_data` does not show.  I have tried dumping the database results using `$wpdb->get_results` and it does not dump the database at all before issuing a 504.  After changing to using a mysqli query, the database results are now dumping the data fine.  But it's now with the arrays and php memory limit being reached as stated in my question.

Comment: What I need is all orders within the past 8 years that people have placed.  Duplicate `_billing_email` is not wanted because we only want these email addresses 1 time only.  Only need to return user email and information 1 time.  But because these users could also be guests, we need to get this information from the orders section, not the users section.  We need this information based on the last time they placed an order on the site.  Woocommerce does not provide a means to export this data either.

Comment: Well, mainly from the `posts` table where `post_type` = 'shop_order'.

Comment: if you are on a shared environment there would not be much effect even if you set ini_set('memory_limit', 0) as the hosting provider would have set a fair value already beyond which the script cant consume memory or you would need a VPS so that you can use the max memory usage. and if you have such a big data of 8 years to deal with, you would need a high memory system even if you have optimized the code to its max.

Comment: This is why it needs to be Streamed where it utlilizes as little PHP Memory as possible, or it atleast releases PHP Memory directly after its use.

Comment: Almost all sites are dealing with some sort of PHP Memory Limitation that the server imposes on it that can't be exceeded.  So, I believe I'm in the majority of people and of sites here.  There are also good reasons for imposing PHP Memory Limits as well.